# Calling no argument constructor of super class

Tags: java

If a class does not provide any constructor,the compiler will provide a default constructor,which in turn call's the no-argument of the super class. Why is this call to the no-argument constructor of the super class needed?

Comment: Your first sentence is not completely accurate. The compiler will **only** provide a default no-argument constructor **if you don't provide any constructors yourself**. As soon as you add a constructor, regardless of how many arguments it accepts, the default no-arguments constructor will **not** be generated by the compiler.

Comment: @ivantod i agree with you....i have corrected it..

Comment: Also for security, what if the super class does not have a no arg constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To initialize the super (inherited) part of that class

Answer (score 2):

So that you can initialize the super class properties as well.

Answer (score 1):

Does it make sense for an object's constructor to only *partially* construct the object?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the "is-a" relationship of subclass instances to their superclass. If a `SpottedFoo` is a subclass of `Foo` (e.g. each `SpottedFoo` "is-a" `Foo`), then the `Foo` constructor should be called.

Otherwise, if there are initializations (private or not) performed by the `Foo` constructor that are skipped, there's no way a `SpottedFoo` can guarantee it can act like a `Foo`.

That's part of the contract for implementation inheritance: each subclass instance must be able to act like any other members of their superclass. This is the [Liskov substitution principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)